# How do I get copyright information to show up in my Eclipse RCP application's "About" dialog

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm using Eclipse's IWorkbenchAction that shows the Eclipse About dialog.

When I use the action in my RCP application the About dialog shows up successfully.

But, when I think proceed to click the "Installation Details" button, I get a dialog with tabs.  I navigate to the "Installed Software" tab, and see my RCP product's name along with its version, and its ID.  I select this item in the table, then proceed to click the "Properties" button.

Once I'm here, I see a dialog that looks similar to Eclipse's Preference dialog.  It has three items to select on the left...  Copyright, General Information, and License Agreement.

I've successfully added my License information to my .product file in order to have it show up when I click the "License Agreement", but...

I can't find where I should put the copyright information in order to get it to show up when I click the "Copyright" item in the list on the left of this dialog.

Where do I add this information so that it will show up here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information comes from p2 `IInstallableUnit`. Are you building your plugins with p2? 
if you implement p2 update you should be able to see this information. p2 build will copy this information from feature.xml.

I am addressing this question:
**"I can't find where I should put the copyright information in order to get it to show up when I click the "Copyright" item in the list on the left of this dialog"**

This copy right information you should get it from feature group when you build with tycho.

For product, there is no copy right information only license info. you put copy right information in feature.xml

Comment: My Eclipse Product isn't a feature.  It contains features, and they have feature.xml files.  Those features have copyright information that is found in the feature.xml file.  I'm using tycho to build, and the only issue I have with copyright information is in the product.  My features are working fine.

Comment: is it p2 update that you are doing? I am not sure the tycho build has issue of copying copy right info from feature.xml.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by, "is it a p2 update that you are doing?"  I'm building an RCP application using tycho.  While I do use p2 to update the RCP application with other features that I'm developing, it seems unrelated to the issue that I'm having.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I was afraid of that.  I wonder why the product doesn't have the ability to display the copyright information in this particular location... yet it does provide for license information display.