# How to access Eclipse RCP .product file license content programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Need to display the license agreement in a custom dialog I have created.

I tried 3 ways. One of which is that I saved the license agreement text in the `.product` file licensing tab. Now all I need is to access this license programmatically so I can feed it to my customDialog class.

Tried `Platform.getProduct().getDefiningBundle().getResource("license");` 
and `Platform.getProduct().getDefiningBundle().getResource("com.magic.rcp.product.licensing"))`

It doesn't work. There doesn't seem to be a method similar to `getVersion()` to get the license agreement.I am running eclipse 3.8.1.

Comment: As far as I can make out this license doesn't end up anywhere useful. The text Eclipse displays in the About dialog for example comes from a property in the `product` defined by the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point.

Comment: I thought that maybe there is a method to access the License once it is saved in the .product file. I even saw a user mention he did it @twindham. I can't comment everywhere yet to ask him how he did it in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630124/how-do-i-get-copyright-information-to-show-up-in-my-eclipse-rcp-applications-a

Comment: I think what that answer is saying is that the .product file is included in the p2 installer repository as an IInstallableUnit. If you include the p2 code in your RCP you should be able to access it via the p2 APIs - but I always find these are a quite complicated to use!

Comment: I will try another way using  IExtensionRegistry to retrieve the extension point and then  IConfigurationElement to get the text.